# R - Add a column that is a result of the unique strings of other columns

Tags: r, string, dataframe, unique

Please: Sorry for my visuals. This is the very first question I drop on SO. I'm working on it.

It should be quite simple, but I just can't get it to work.
Based on two columns, stored with strings, I would like to create a new column that contains the unique string(s) of those two columns.

Example:
I have:

```
df_A <- data.frame(V1 = c("A","","","B"), V2 = c("","","B","B"))
```

When I try this:

```
df_A$V3 <- unique(df_A$V1,df_A$V2)
```

The third row is missing the string "B"

This is what I would like to get, column "V4":

```
df_A$V4 <- c("A","","B","B")
```

Comment: `df_A$V3 = apply(X = df_A, MARGIN = 1, function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse = ""))`

Answer (score 1):

```
df_A$V3 = apply(X = df_A, MARGIN = 1, function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse = ""))
```

The comment d.b. posted is the best way to do this.  In case you wanted an explanation of what is going on here, I thought I'd add a community wiki.

`apply` is used to apply a function to a data frame

`MARGIN = 1` specifies row operations, while

`MARGIN = 2` is for columns.
the function being applied here is pasting the actual unique values, while ignoring NULLs.